# PHPExcel file no longer writing

Tags: php, sql, phpexcel

I can't figure out what went wrong here but previously this was exporting an excel file but only with headers, no data.

Now it is printing that it successfully connected to the database, then the job finishes without errors but it doesn't create a new excel file. I changed it to use PDO which is when it stopped printing the file altogether.

How can I change this to properly create/write to the file and actually print my result rows from my query?

```
    $DB2Dev = new PDO("odbc:DSN=connnection1;", "user", "password");
    if($DB2Dev){
            $connectionMessage =  "DB2 connection successful";
            print_r($connectionMessage);
        }else{
            $connectionMessage = "DB2 NOT CONNECTED!";
            print_r($connectionMessage);
        }
    $DB2Dev->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    //Create and run query
    $sql = "
    SELECT manager, count(*) as items
      from items
    where start_date >= '2019-01-01'
    group by manager
    order by manager";


    try {
        $itemDetails = $DB2conn->prepare($sql);
        $detailRslt = $itemDetails->execute();

    }catch(PDOException $ex) {
        $detailSelectError = "QUERY ONE FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
    }

    $phpExcel = new PHPExcel;
    $sheet = $phpExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet ->setTitle("Item Counts");
    $sheet ->getColumnDimension('A') -> setAutoSize(true);
    $sheet ->getColumnDimension('B') -> setAutoSize(true);



    //Create header row
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Manager');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Items');

    $rowCount = 1;

    while($row = $itemDetails->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        var_dump($row);
        $sheet->setCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['manager']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['items']);

        $rowCount++;
    }

    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpExcel, "Excel2007");
    $writer->save('Item Counts.xlsx');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because '$DB2conn' doesn't exist when you use it. I think it should be $DB2Dev. IF you fix it this script will execute correct.